# What should I consider when I am doing an authentication process with a titanium app?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, signing

Hello it's my first time doing a sign in process in a mobile app with Titanium and I wonder what information should I save and the best practice to do it?

My server is configured in this way:

- The server requires I send a user and password and if the information match it will provide a token session.

This is the code I use for signing in:

```
 function signIn(e) {

//function to use HTTP to connect to a web server and transfer the data.
var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onerror : function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('There was an error during the connection');
    },
    timeout : 100000,
});
//Here you have to change it for your local ip
sendit.open('POST', 'http://myserver');
var params = {
    user : $.txtUsuario.value,
    password : $.txtPassword.value
};
sendit.send(params);
//Function to be called upon a successful response
sendit.onload = function() {
    var json = this.responseText;  
    var response = JSON.parse(json);  
    if (response.success == "true")  
    {  
        var landing = Alloy.createController("menu").getView();
        $.index.close();
        landing.open();

    }  
    else  
    {  
        alert(response);  
    }  
};
};
```

the code above is working, however I do not know how to manage the sign out. I would like my application works like the most apps do, e.g:

You sign in once and after that if you do not close the app you are able to continues using it and even making a request.

Thank you for any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your app requirements. for exemple if you will use the token in your app later you can save it as an [AppProperty](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties) :

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('token',yourTokenGoHere);
```

and in the app starting you can get it back :

```
var myToken = Ti.App.Properties.getString('token');
```

and then you can make a test for example if the token is still valid or not :

```
if(myToken === 'invalidtoken')
   youSholdLogin();
else 
   youCanGoFurther();
```

and when the user disconnect rest the token to be invalid :

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('token', 'invalidtoken');
```

Comment: Thank you Coyote, one more time you are demonstrate that you are an expert with Titanum, thank you for helping me. Let me try this, I'm going to check the link and I will let you know when it works